# Variadic template package pack unpacking as parameters for factory delegate

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I've the following template based method to create a factory delegate functor for my IOCContainer:

```
template <typename T, typename ... D>
void wire(void)
{
   std::type_index type = typeid(T);

   auto iter = m_repository.begin();
   while(iter!=m_repository.end()){
    if((iter->first) == type ||
     (iter->second)->getType() == type){
      break;
    }
    iter++;
   }

   auto delegate = [this]() -> T * {
     return new T(this->resolve<D>()...);
   };

   auto component = iter->second;
   component->setResolver(std::shared_ptr<Resolver>(new DelegateResolver<T>(delegate, this)));
}
```

With this method it's possible to create a new transient object instance of T which contains
multiple dependencies D. The dependencies are resolved dynamically on creation of the delegate. This works fine
for any dependency resolved strictly by type.

However I've also types registered by contract (as concrete implementation of an interface or abstract
class) which could referenced by name. By this reason I've to regard parameters on dependency wiring
too. How could I archive this?

First I've thought to use a simple template for my dependencies which holds the required parameters
and could be set as parameter at resolve:

```
template <typename D>
void resolve(const D& dependency) {}
```

The implementation of this template is easy. And I could write an extra template function which allowes me
to wire those dependencies:

```
template <typename T, typename ... D>
void wire(const D&... dependencies)
{}
```

But how I could unpack the variadic template parameter pack at the resolve call on delegate functor
creation? To get a resolve call like this:

```
auto delegate = [this]() -> T * {
    return new T(this->resolve<D>(D)...);
};
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: the same way as using [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward): `new T(this->resolve<D>(dependencies)...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to send `dependency` as an argument:

```
auto delegate = [this]() -> T * {
    return new T(this->resolve(dependency)...);
};
```

Comment: You should use `std::make_shared` for exception-safety.

Comment: I thought this also first. But it doesn't work. If I use this expression I got the compiler error that the dependencies are not captured

Comment: @Hellhound Try capturing using `&`.

Comment: @Hellhound If that doesn't work, can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with lambda expressions. Where should I use the & operator?

Comment: @Hellhound `[&] () { ... }`

Comment: If I replace this with & in lambda expression I got the compile failure that the parameter pack could not expanded.

Comment: @Hellhound What compiler are you running this on? What does the error say exactly?

Comment: @Hellhound I managed to decompose it down and I'm not getting any errors -- http://rextester.com/AZXN5522

Comment: I tested your code, it fails also with the following failure output: [Compile Failure](http://pastebin.com/CPfhv4W1)

Comment: Using GCC 4.8.1 on Linux and Windows platform.

Comment: @Hellhound Can you show me the code you're using please?

Comment: As promised I've cleaned the projectcode and make it runable as standalone test. You can download the actual IOC testcode including google tests here: [https://sourceforge.net/projects/binrevengine/files/publications/].

Comment: Meanwhile I figured out that this issue is related to a GCC 4.8 bug, based on expanding the template variadics: [GCC Bug in Lambda expression](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/1ink22/pass_argument_pack_to_lambda_in_c11/). Any idea how I could get a workaround for object construction?

Comment: I've upgraded the GCC to 4.9.1. Now the issue with the lambda expression looks like solved. But I got still a problem with the resolve. If I use the source from the answer snipped, the compile fails, because the lambda expression place-in of the resolve call doesn't contains the result of the call, it contains the type of the dependency which is unknown by the constructor argument.